# Array of objects in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, object, parameters

I am trying to learn ruby and have a doubt regarding passing arrays of objects as function parameters and printing it in the function.

I have an array that contains an array of objects as follows

```
describe Name
par1 = "John"
par2 = "Miley"
par3 = "Maria"
@obj_arr = [Name.new(par1),Name.new(par2),Name.new(par3)]
Name.func1(@obj_arr)
```

I want to print the name "John", "Miley" and "Maria" in the function and I wrote the function func1 is as follows :

```
def self.func1(parameter)
parameter.each do |p|
puts p
end
end
```

This did not print the names. Am I going wrong in accessing the obj_arr in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be the to_s method of the object. You should override it to print what you want. BTW, the syntax in your question is a bit off. I think the definition of the function should be def self.func1 and that your missing an end.
This is the code I tested:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Name
irb(main):002:1> def self.func1(parameter)
irb(main):003:2> parameter.each do |p|
irb(main):004:3* puts p
irb(main):005:3> end
irb(main):006:2> end
irb(main):007:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> class Name
irb(main):009:1> def initialize(name)
irb(main):010:2> @name = name
irb(main):011:2> end
irb(main):012:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> Name.func1([Name.new('a'), Name.new('b')])
#<Name:0x2163dc8>
#<Name:0x2163d98>
=> [#<Name:0x2163dc8 @name="a">, #<Name:0x2163d98 @name="b">]
irb(main):014:0> class Name
irb(main):015:1> def to_s
irb(main):016:2> @name
irb(main):017:2> end
irb(main):018:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):019:0> Name.func1([Name.new('a'), Name.new('b')])
a
b
=> [a, b]
irb(main):020:0>
```

Comment: he is missing 2 ends actually

Comment: Should I convert each parameter in the function into a string and then print?

Comment: I added some code in the answer. I think it should answer the question. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that func1 is defined on a instance of class Name and not the class itself?

Try:

```
  class Name
    def self.func1(parameter)
      parameter.each do |p|
        puts p
      end   
    end 
  end
```